# How to output 10 results in a row using PHP?

Tags: php, html

i am trying to output 10  inside each

the result should look like this

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
</tr>
```

here's my code but the problem is it keeps outputting  inside single

```
    <table class="tfhgg" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="vg22">
            <th colspan="10">items</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="yghj">

        <?php
            $a = "Hello";
            foreach ($a as $key) {
                        echo'<td class="gjhj">Hello</td>';
            }
        ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

hope some one could help me with this. thanks

```
<?php
                $a = scandir("./");
                    foreach ($a as $key) {
                        if($key != "." && $key != ".." && $key != "index.php") {
                            ob_start();
                            require $key."/index.php";
                            ob_end_clean();
                            if($cont3 == "Live TV") {
                                for ($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) {
                                echo '<tr class="tvtdb">';
                                echo'<td class="tvtd">Hello/td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            ?>
```

just edited #1
here is my complete code but this repeats same thing again and again it is not creating td inside tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here you go.

```
<table style="border:1px solid #444;" class="tvschtb" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <th colspan="4">table head</th>
</tr>
<tr>

<?php

    $cnt =0;
    $a = scandir("./");
        foreach ($a as $key) {
        
            if($key != "." && $key != ".." && $key != "index.php") {
                echo '<td style="border:1px solid #444;">'.$key."</td>";
                $cnt++;
            }
    
            if($cnt==4){
                $cnt=0;
                echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }
?>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: appreciate your time and hard work even saying thank you is not really enough. i do really appreciate it. may i ask sir where did you learn coding php and if you have any advise for me ? cause i am big fan of coding and love coding that code was my own made . i am not a good coder but i am trying sir and i wish i could learn any sooner.

Comment: if you really want to learn coding the best intro online course is CS50.  It is the most popular course at Harvard and you can do it online for free at https://www.edx.org/course/cs50s-introduction-to-computer-science

Comment: hi. brother are you there ? i just want to ask a question about mySQL. it is not coding or something

Comment: if i want to make something like this https://prnt.sc/trur76 how would my SQL structure would be ? i was thinking to make it like... i make database called "mydb" then i make 3 tables each table will be for date as you see in the picture then all matches or games inside it in rows or columns. but there's another guys told me to make a table and put date with them like this " date , game , time , cat , url " if i make it like this, there will be multiple same date like this https://prnt.sc/truu5h

Comment: what i am trying to make in database something like Database=>"mydb", Table=>"matches" and inside matches will be all games but there's many games with same date and the output must output the date only once but if there's many same date it will output all of them not like this https://prnt.sc/trur76 . but if i make table for each date it will be ok

Comment: what i am thinking is, making table for each date is the right way or i am wrong ? because that guy told me to make as he said so i got confused

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<tr>
    <?php 
    $count = 10; 
    for ($i = 0; count > $i; $i++){
         echo "<td>hello {$i}</td>"
    }
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a little more complete:

```
<table>

   <?php 

       for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){ ?>
           <tr>
           <?php for($j=1;$j<11;$j++){ ?>
               <td>  <?php echo $j; ?></td>
           <?php } ?>  
           </tr>   
       <?php } ?> 
</table>
```

Comment: can i go to chat with you sir so i can share with you my code

Comment: thanks. there was an option here on stackoverflow to go to chat i think only who answer can get me to chat

Comment: or some one with higher level user can create room. my account is new you know. look at footer of page sir

Comment: it is saying that i don't have enough rapitation

Comment: check bottom of my question sir i just posted my code

Comment: your code doesn't make any sense to me.  what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: the point is .. for each folder that is inside $a value will be assigned to a $key variable and it should output each folder with echo $key variable. so the output will be like bunch of <td><td><td><td><td><td> with no <tr></tr> tags to seperate them

Comment: so you don't want the numbers 1-10 appearing in the td's?

Comment: also, what does require $key."/index.php"; suppose to do?

Comment: it is very hard for me to explain sir. do you have skype and teamviewer sir i will open teamviewer you can see it on my screen

Comment: right now my code is outputting all <td><td> for each $key. i need it to output 10 of <td></td> inside each <tr></tr> for eample if there's more than $key value for example 30.. it must create 3 of <tr></tr> and inside each and one of them put 10 <td></td>

Comment: here is the complete work sir test it and hope you can help me solve this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PPNx3P1U4319lGaqjtwZZQxzH7WKEyPH/view?usp=sharing